# Access database positive value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I'm programming in vb.net and the point is to interact with a database, I've come to a point where I need to enter a price. The problem is I can enter a negative price, I know in SQL you can put a value as unsigned like c++ but in access I'm really confuse on how to do it.

The point is I don't want to deal with the negative number in my program I want it defined by the dataSet in my program who he take it from the database rule

```
dAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Articles", connection)
dSet = New DataSet("Datatable")

'Vas chercher les donner dans la DB et creer une dataset heriter de datatable avec comme reader "Articles_table"
With connection
    .Open()
    dAdapter.Fill(dSet, "Articles_table")
    .Close()
End With

'Definie la column 1 index 0 comme etant unique m'evite de gerer la supression l'addition de colone et les doublons
Dim table = dSet.Tables("Articles_table")
table.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {table.Columns(0)}

'Peuple la grid
With DataGridView1
    .DataSource = dSet
    .DataMember = "Articles_table"
End With
```

In this code the program connect to the acces database fill the data set and bind it to a DataGridView with the first column as the primarykey who,s unique.

I guess My question is: How can I define the second and third column as positive number only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt Access has support for a data type with only positive numbers. If I was in your shoes I would check something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx for data type comparison and not spend too much time on it; instead move the positive/negative check to the business layer.